# Control Drag Drop

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, controls

I have a user control in c# on a windows form the drag drop events are only being fired around the edge of the control, does anyone have a clue what is causing this its driving me mad!?

```
private void flowDiagram1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
  else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void flowDiagram1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (!m_bDragging)
    flowDiagram1_DragDrop(sender, e);
}

private void flowDiagram1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Drop");
}
```

Comment: cant provide code for the control its just a dll im using but it seems to happen even if i create my own controls but when im dragging/dropping im simply doing the following

Comment: private void flowDiagram1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

        }

        private void flowDiagram1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!m_bDragging)
                flowDiagram1_DragDrop(sender, e);
        }

        private void flowDiagram1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Drop");
        }

Comment: problem only occurs when dropping onto a control if its just a panel of something then its ok

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add this to drag over too:

```
if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
  else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
```